# DateTime Format "dd/MM/yyyy" on ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

How I can show `DateTime` like this `dd/MM/yyyy`?

Here my code

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? kayittarihi { get; set; }
```

and

```
@{                          
   var kayittarihi = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

When I do it this way

[image: Here is an example of the date/time format.]

Comment: What is expected output here? And what are you getting instead? You want date to be displayed in this format in UI or you want it to be stored in dba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the slash with a single quote like `'/'`

So `dd'/'MM'/'yyyy`

This is needed because the `/` is a meta character in the format string for dates.

> The "/" custom format specifier represents the date separator, which is used to differentiate years, months, and days
>
> To change the date separator for a particular date and time string, specify the separator character within a literal string delimiter. For example, the custom format string mm'/'dd'/'yyyy produces a result string in which "/" is always used as the date separator.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

See this live demo [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JVZCV6)

```
//ko-KR uses dashes for datetime format by default
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy",new CultureInfo("ko-KR"))); //21-04-2017
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy",new CultureInfo("ko-KR"))); //21/04/2017
```

Comment: This time it came like this "21/MM.2017" and didnt work

Comment: @ÖmerFarukArslan Was a mistake in my answer, updated it. Please retest

Comment: Added a demo in the .NET Fiddle :)

Comment: it worked, but still like this 2017-04-21 00:00:00.000 on database . How ı can ı destroyed the zeros?

Comment: And ı am trying to make  this way "day / month / year". But does'nt.

Comment: DateTime consists of both a date component and a Time component; both within System.DateTime and within the SQL datetime data type. You could change the table schema to a `date`type to save 5 bytes per instance, but it will still be a _full_ `DateTime` when you bring it into the application and have the HMS values as zeroes.

Comment: İts didnt work. DateTime still like this 2017-04-22 00:00:00.000 in sql database. How ı can make 22/04/2017 ? Pls help me .

Answer (score 0):

add `<globalization culture="en-GB" />` inside of `<system.web> </system.web>` 
 in your `web.config` and check.
you can also try

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy",new CultureInfo("en-GB")));
```

If you using **Entity Framework**  and store formatted data in **sql server** then

at first create a data conversion class

```
   public DateConvention()
    {
        Properties<DateTime>()
            .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<DataTypeAttribute>()
            .Any(a => a.DataType == DataType.Date))
            .Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("date"));

    }
```

then

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
      //Your DbSet

     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

           //Your modelBuilder

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new DateConvention());
    }
}
```